# `ListStepPlot` with horizontal error bands

Tags: plotting, intervals

I want to plot a diagram with `ListStepPlot` and the error bars are plotted as rectangles around the data points.

MME:

```
Block[{tmp = 100}, 
  Table[{n, 
    Around[tmp = tmp - RandomReal[{0, 7}], RandomReal[{0, 5}]]}, {n, 
    1, 10}]];
ListStepPlot[%, Center, PlotRange -> All, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
ListPlot[%%, PlotRange -> All, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Joined -> True]
```

The second plot would give a desired error band style, but the placement of the band (as well as the joined lines) are wrong. The data points should be at the center of the lines/bands, but they are actually at the left end of the lines/bands. The first one has the correct placement of data points, but it gives a joined band, not the one in the second plot. Also, in the first plot, the first and last points both lost some part of error band, and in the second plot, the error band of the last point is completely lost.

How should I plot the desired diagram?